# CSS Position background element to cover parents/parent

Tags: css

How can I make the green background to cover all the `.section` class?

I have this structure:

```
section   // one section will have one container
   ->container // one container can have multiple elements
   ->elements // the background class set here should override the section
```

relation everywhere and I would like to define a "background" element that covers the whole section.

Note:
I am getting the data like(`section/container/elements`) this and it is not going to change.

There is possible to have multiple sections each with it's own background.

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="background green" />
    <div>
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/hfbLmvs1/)

[image]

Comment: If you want different colors for your sections, why not give the `section` element a color class instead of having a `.background` div inside the container with the color class?

Comment: What's the goal of this design? Are you just trying to have a background-color or are you explicitly trying to hide/obscure the content of the sections? I ask because while it seems odd to want to use a child element to act as the background for its ancestor, but we don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I updated the question, I hope it's a bit more clear. The structure exists... I just need to make a "background" element work.

Answer (score 0):

**you Should style give tag section**

```
background-color: green;
```

Comment: this is not an option to change the section.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `position` of `.section` to `relative`, and set the `position` of `.green` to `absolute`.

Now the position, width & height will use `.section` as reference.

Then you could set these properties freely.

here is the code:

```css
.section{
  position: relative;
}

.green {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

and then you may have to adjust their `z-index`

```
.green {
  z-index: -1;
}

.section {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

> absolute: The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. **It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any;** otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#syntax)

Comment: Thanks, thought about it, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

One approach, with explanatory comments in the code, is as below:

```css
/* simple reset to ensure no browser-default padding/margin exists,
   and forces all element-size calculations to include border-width
   and padding inside the defined width: */
*,::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  /* all values here are purely aesthetic, adjust to your own
     requirements: */
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 80vmin;
  width: 80vmin;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.container {
  /* here we use grid layout on the .container element(s): */
  display: grid;
  /* we specify one grid-column and one grid-row, each of which
     take 100% of the available space: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  /* sizing the grid to be 100% of the parent's width/height: */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* all <div> elements that are children of the .container: */
.container > div {
  /* are placed in the first grid-column and first grid-row: */
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  /* specifying a max-height and max-width of 100% to address
     potential overflow; obviusly adjust to your requirements: */
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* styling the element that will hold the contents (so far as your
   demo shows): */
.container > div:last-child {
  /* hiding overflow on x-axis: */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* allowing scrolling on the y-axis to see
     overflowing content: */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* defining some white-space between the element edges and contents
     within: */
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.blue {
  background-color: hsl(180 65% 81% / 0.5);
}
.green {
  background-color: hsl(120 93% 79% / 0.5);
}

.yellow {
  background-color: hsl(60 100% 50% / 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="background blue" />
    <div>
        Some very short content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="background green" />
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat corporis hic sunt nam perferendis assumenda asperiores nobis quae consequatur aut ut quidem id, optio consequuntur ipsa labore consectetur nihil incidunt.</p>
        <p>Minima quibusdam hic culpa, ea porro vitae asperiores! Vitae odit, delectus nesciunt asperiores maxime. Voluptatum velit repellendus in. Impedit laudantium asperiores nostrum neque laboriosam eius libero fugiat itaque inventore nulla?</p>
        <p>Laboriosam quod, facilis ratione quas consequatur quis quisquam vel eius velit eveniet, excepturi voluptatem ea dicta quam eaque praesentium sequi illum, optio animi! Libero minima iste, maiores temporibus reiciendis repellendus.</p>
        <p>Blanditiis reiciendis eveniet perspiciatis excepturi, nulla eum, rem atque. Perspiciatis quae sed autem officiis error, earum officia, nulla quod, velit deleniti pariatur. Obcaecati inventore, in adipisci eveniet, expedita a quaerat.</p>
        <p>Quaerat labore vitae iure expedita eaque nostrum distinctio et, atque velit quisquam corporis animi, aut voluptatem itaque odio ipsum. Iusto asperiores eius at quos totam voluptatum, ratione voluptate cum quas.</p>
        <p>Sed minima aliquid voluptatum minus dolores, iusto, ducimus doloribus! Aliquam quae, atque! Iusto nobis alias magnam minima, impedit iste illo iure illum doloremque debitis! Ipsa assumenda soluta fugiat ut esse.</p>
        <p>Sint voluptatum suscipit laborum, aliquid eveniet odit blanditiis corporis voluptatibus, rem consectetur quam quidem saepe, doloremque, sit nihil rerum voluptas deleniti a expedita quo quod beatae modi. Incidunt, aliquid. Ea.</p>
        <p>Minus, dicta sed maiores amet necessitatibus eaque magnam asperiores, aperiam, qui earum numquam sequi eius provident officiis. Illum fuga earum architecto nesciunt ut beatae mollitia quod sunt nulla. Ipsum, modi?</p>
        <p>Eligendi, officiis maxime cupiditate consectetur voluptates est ullam odio, porro sint cum suscipit rerum nisi quibusdam non enim repudiandae facere fugiat repellendus possimus, sequi excepturi culpa iusto. Velit, sunt deleniti!</p>
        <p>Ipsa deserunt dolorum molestias reiciendis. Ad dolorum eius suscipit, sapiente laboriosam dolor sequi, accusamus id consequuntur modi aliquid, architecto fuga illum non voluptatum quod. Molestiae deserunt maxime suscipit tenetur, tempora.</p>
        <p>Id non fugit in vitae. Fuga voluptates sapiente, impedit atque, quasi, consequatur autem sunt dignissimos unde nam quam! Officiis quos, distinctio facilis illum explicabo incidunt quia pariatur minima, enim at.</p>
        <p>Commodi consectetur repellendus ad assumenda eius voluptatibus tempora dolor et possimus quaerat aperiam nesciunt qui optio, sapiente ab libero iste, recusandae, suscipit obcaecati accusamus perferendis minus molestias. Nisi, inventore, explicabo?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="background yellow" />
    <div>
        Some very short content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g086wopy/).

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [CSS Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`hsl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl).
- [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height).
- [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).
- [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).
- [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x).
- [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`vmin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vmin).
- [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).